# Authentication failed with mongodb atlas

Tags: mongodb

MongoError: bad auth : Authentication failed.
at MessageStream.messageHandler (C:\Users\formi\Documents\code\portfolio--my-bubble-server\node_modules\mongodb\lib\cmap\connection.js:268:20)
at MessageStream.emit (node:events:513:28)
at MessageStream.emit (node:domain:489:12)
at processIncomingData (C:\Users\formi\Documents\code\portfolio--my-bubble-server\node_modules\mongodb\lib\cmap\message_stream.js:144:12)
at MessageStream._write (C:\Users\formi\Documents\code\portfolio--my-bubble-server\node_modules\mongodb\lib\cmap\message_stream.js:42:5)
at writeOrBuffer (node:internal/streams/writable:392:12)
at _write (node:internal/streams/writable:333:10)
at MessageStream.Writable.write (node:internal/streams/writable:337:10)
at TLSSocket.ondata (node:internal/streams/readable:766:22)
at TLSSocket.emit (node:events:513:28)
at TLSSocket.emit (node:domain:489:12)
at addChunk (node:internal/streams/readable:324:12)
at readableAddChunk (node:internal/streams/readable:297:9)
at TLSSocket.Readable.push (node:internal/streams/readable:234:10)
at TLSWrap.onStreamRead (node:internal/stream_base_commons:190:23) {
ok: 0,
code: 8000,
codeName: 'AtlasError'
} connection successful

```
import express from 'express'
import mongoose from 'mongoose'
import 'dotenv/config'
import { retrieveWhileTechCollection, retrieveWholeProjectCollection, 
retriveAllOfProjectAndTechCollections, retrivedataForLandingSite } from 
'./routes/retrieveData'
import updateMyData from './routes/updateMyData'
import cors from 'cors'

const app = express()
const port = process.env.PORT || 8001

app.use(cors())

app.use('/demo', retrieveWholeProjectCollection, retrieveWhileTechCollection)
app.use('/', retriveAllOfProjectAndTechCollections, updateMyData, retrivedataForLandingSite)

app.listen(port, () => console.log(`server started at http://localhost:${port}`))

mongoose.connect(process.env.MONGO_URI, {
  useCreateIndex: true, useNewUrlParser: true, useUnifiedTopology: true
}, () => console.log('connected to db'))

mongoose.connection
  .once('open', () => console.log('connection successful'))
  .on('error', (error) => console.log(error, 'connection successful'))
```

env file:
MONGO_URI=mongodb+srv://username:password@cluster0.wvtkc.mongodb.net/?retryWrites=true&w=majority

Comment: Checking just in case -- does the URL in your environment literally have the words "username" and "password", or have you substituted your actual username and password?

Comment: See this one: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63754742/authentication-failure-while-trying-to-save-to-mongodb/63755470#63755470